# What is the cyclic subgroup of integers(Z) generated by -1 under +?

Tags: cyclic-groups

I am trying to understand cyclic, and need to know what the cyclic subgroup of integers (Z) generated by -1 under + ?

Answer (score 3):

Keep adding $-1$ to itself; what do you get?  Then don't forget that subgroups include the inverses; what is the additive inverse of $-1$, and what do you get when you add that to itself?  That is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ you get.  (Note that subgroups don't have to be proper.)

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup would be denoted $\langle -1 \rangle$ and the set of elements of the group is
$$\{ \dots , (-1)^{-2}, (-1)^{-1}, (-1)^0, (-1)^1, (-1)^2, \dots \}$$
where $(-1)^n=\underbrace{(-1)+\cdots +(-1)}_\text{$n$-many}$ for $n>0$.